without sudo, pkcs11-tool doesn't show all slots
I want to list all active slots in softhsm2 by using --list-slots. But pkcs11-tool provide different results when I use with and without sudo:
sudo pkcs11-tool --module /usr/local/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so --list-slots
Available slots:
Slot 0 (0x3820801b): SoftHSM slot ID 0x3820801b
  token label        : Test Token
  token manufacturer : SoftHSM project
  token model        : SoftHSM v2
  token flags        : login required, rng, SO PIN count low, token initialized, PIN initialized, other flags=0x20
  hardware version   : 2.6
  firmware version   : 2.6
  serial num         : 9fdf8adcb820801b
  pin min/max        : 4/255
Slot 1 (0x4224455f): SoftHSM slot ID 0x4224455f
  token label        : hellotoken
  token manufacturer : SoftHSM project
  token model        : SoftHSM v2
  token flags        : login required, rng, token initialized, PIN initialized, other flags=0x20
  hardware version   : 2.6
  firmware version   : 2.6
  serial num         : 09890b8c4224455f
  pin min/max        : 4/255
Slot 2 (0x46f8c6dc): SoftHSM slot ID 0x46f8c6dc
  token label        : mytoken1
  token manufacturer : SoftHSM project
  token model        : SoftHSM v2
  token flags        : login required, rng, SO PIN count low, token initialized, PIN initialized, other flags=0x20
  hardware version   : 2.6
  firmware version   : 2.6
  serial num         : ecabb343c6f8c6dc
  pin min/max        : 4/255
Slot 3 (0x74a6136e): SoftHSM slot ID 0x74a6136e
  token label        : token-label
  token manufacturer : SoftHSM project
  token model        : SoftHSM v2
  token flags        : login required, rng, token initialized, PIN initialized, other flags=0x20
  hardware version   : 2.6
  firmware version   : 2.6
  serial num         : 51a8110974a6136e
  pin min/max        : 4/255
Slot 4 (0x4): SoftHSM slot ID 0x4
  token state:   uninitialized

and
without sudo
pkcs11-tool --module /usr/local/lib/softhsm/libsofthsm2.so --list-slots
Available slots:
Slot 0 (0x3820801b): SoftHSM slot ID 0x3820801b
  token label        : Test Token
  token manufacturer : SoftHSM project
  token model        : SoftHSM v2
  token flags        : login required, rng, SO PIN count low, token initialized, PIN initialized, other flags=0x20
  hardware version   : 2.6
  firmware version   : 2.6
  serial num         : 9fdf8adcb820801b
  pin min/max        : 4/255
Slot 1 (0x1): SoftHSM slot ID 0x1
  token state:   uninitialized

How to solve this?

Which distro? I can only use softhsm as root on Debian.

@garethTheRed yes, you are correct, it was about access permission, I need to grant it to read the tokendir. Thank you
